# Efficiently copy data from Azure blob storage to S3

Tags: python, azure, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to move ~1 million files from Azure storage to S3. I wrote this python script using Azure python sdk and boto3.

```
marker = None
while True:
    batch = azure_blob_service.list_blobs(
        container, marker=marker)
    # copy blobs in batches
    for blob in batch:
        blob_name = blob.name
        current_blob = azure_blob_service.get_blob_to_bytes(
            copy_from_container, blob_name)
        s3_client.put_object(
            Body=current_blob.content,
            Bucket=s3_bucket,
            ContentType=current_blob.properties.content_settings.content_type,
            Key=blob_name)
    if not batch.next_marker:
        break
    marker = batch.next_marker
```

But this is slow.

How can I move data efficiently from azure to S3?

Comment: It's been really long that I have worked with S3 so I may be wrong but S3 doesn't support server-side copying. Correct? Only option available to you is download blobs from Azure to your local disk and then upload it back to S3. Right?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, I didn't find anything like that. I am also doing something similar to you. But instead of downloading them to disk, I am using `get_blob_to_bytes` and then uploading that to S3.

Comment: `get_blob_to_bytes` .... you're still downloading the data. What you're not doing is saving this data to local disk so from network perspective, you're not gaining anything.

Comment: Correct. It's same. Looking for some solution to migrate prod data from azure to S3. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Please look at my answer and see if it makes any sense.

Comment: Have you tried using [upload_fileobj](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj)? That's a managed transfer that will upload in multiple parts in multiple threads. If Azure will give you a stream then you can pass that in so that your memory overhead is minimized.

Comment: Yes we can get stream using `get_blob_to_stream` from azure. Can you help me figure out how I can use it?

Answer (score 2):

Considering S3 does not support server-side async copy blob like Azure Blob Storage, in order to move  data from Azure Storage to S3, you would need to first download the blobs from Azure Storage and then upload them back to S3. This is where Internet speed comes into play as you are downloading and uploading lots of data.

If you want to speed up the whole process one alternative would be to run this script in a VM in Amazon itself (ideally in the same region as your S3 account). That way you will be able to download much faster (assuming Amazon offers better Internet speeds than what you currently have) and then upload it faster as well as you will be uploading in the same region.

Comment: Currently I'm doing it on Azure VM. Will it make difference doing it on EC2 instead?

Comment: Hmmm.....interesting question. I think if we take VMs with the same configuration, then it should be more or less the same. Are your Azure VM and Storage account in the same region?

Comment: No. Azure VM and Storage are in one region while S3 is in another.

Comment: Obviously:). S3 and Azure will be in different regions :). I have only tried the other way around so I wouldn't know for sure if running the script in EC2 will make things faster. My answer was based on the assumption that you're running this script locally. I guess you just have to try it out.

Comment: I meant my Azure resources are in Singapore and S3 is in US East 1. I will try out other ways. Thanks for your input :)